# OpenCV VideoCapture cant open/read url

Tags: python, opencv

My current OpenCV version is 2.4.13. Python version is 2.7.11. My operating system is OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. I've been trying to use VideoCapture() to read url but keep getting this:

**WARNING: Couldn't read movie file**

VideoCapture() works fine with my laptop's webcam and local files. For example, I can open and play video like this:

**cv2.VideoCapture("sg04video.mov")**

But I am trying to access my ip camera with OpenCV. At first I thought I had the wrong url or it was some authentication problem. I disabled authentication, tried several camera urls(both rtsp and http) and could open them in VLC player. VLC player can also open other resources like this one: [random rtsp video link](http://rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov)

I even managed to open the url for capturing camera view image in my browser.

But cv2.VideoCapture cant open any of those urls, both video and image, whether its for my own camera or from the internet. Im sure the problem is not with the ip camera.

I am relatively new to programming and I installed OpenCV following this guide:

[Installing OpenCV 2.4.9 on Mac OSX with Python Support](https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/)

Please help!! Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, Katrina. Perhaps this is occuring because of how python handles escape keys etc. When you pass a URL into python, make sure you double up every back or forward slash. For example

```  path = 'path\\to\\image ' ```